# How to remove everything from the URL after / symbol?

Tags: jquery

My URL could look like:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/?sfid=422&_sft_category=ogilvy
```

I need the URL to change after a click and become

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/
```

No other action needed, just a change of the URL string. So basically I need to eliminate `?sfid=422&_sft_category=ogilvy` But that is dynamic so everything after `http://www.example.com/xchanges/` could be anything

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 ..Change url...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the ulr string in two parts with `split()` function.

Then just keep the first part (before `?`) using `pop()`

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7a5vv6x6/1/) (check the console)

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/xchanges/?sfid=422&_sft_category=ogilvy';

var arr = url.split('?');
arr.pop();
console.log(arr[0]);
```

**EDIT** (In order to navigate)

```
window.location.href = arr[0];
```

**EDIT #2**

First, you get the current url (whatever it is) and store it in a variable:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Then you proceed as above (split the url, keep the first part only and redirect the page to this url)

```js
$('#change').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('span').text();

  var arr = url.split('?');
  arr.pop();
  //alert(arr[0]);
  window.location.href = arr[0];
});
```

```css
span {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#change {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>http://www.example.com/xchanges/?sfid=422&_sft_category=ogilvy</span>

<div id="change">change</div>
```

Comment: sorry but how will the URL change? Ok the console.log but what about the actual URL in browser?

Comment: What if we need to change the URL in the actual address bar tho?

Comment: Check my edit. You can use window.location.href and pass the new url (arr[0])

Comment: and what about if everything after the / is dynamic? that is assuming we have a defined string right? What if that string after / is dynamic?

Comment: literally i need a general way of removing everything after http://www.example.com/

Comment: ok this works but it is loading the page to the new location, I only need the URL string to change with no other action e.g. no new page load

Answer (score 0):

```
'http://www.example.com/xchanges/?sfid=422&_sft_category=ogilvy'.replace(/[^\/]*$/, '')
```

This will remove string after the last symbol `/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery, split, replace, or Regex using the [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

```
const changeURL = ( event ) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    window.location.href = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
}

document.querySelector( '.filter a' ).addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    changeURL( event )
})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var geturl = InputUrl

StringBuilder BuildUrl = new StringBuilder();

String[] separated = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(geturl, "[% ? / & =]");

for(int i =0; separated.Length > i; i++)
{
    BuildUrl.Append("" + separated[i] + "");
}
```

Comment: Passing the Parameter Url in InputUrl Variable, then Split the Url Like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220898/how-to-get-links-to-urls-in-text-in-asp-net-mvc-4-with-razor-syntax) string[0], string[1]...  For loop To find The Array for string

Comment: The question is about jQuery while your answer is irrelevant. You should also provide more explanation to the code if it is helpful