# MVC Turn model text into clickable link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC Razor view that pulls change log information from a database (a table which only I have access to, limiting security concerns).

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The description will contain values like `New page available: http://localhost:0000/app/NewItem`. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make that web address active.

I.e., turn *`New page available: http://localhost:0000/app/NewItem`*

into: *New page available: http://localhost:0000/app/NewItem*

and have the link properly rendered on the page. Is there a simple way to accomplish this, short of using regular expressions in the controller to pull that link out?

Comment: First, I'd consider storing the link as a separate property. Then make a [custom template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710140/how-do-i-create-a-mvc-razor-template-for-displayfor) for the property that will output your description with the link wrapped in an anchor.

Comment: That's going to be my fall back if there isn't an easier way to do it.

Comment: I don't know the details of your application. But seems to me that is the easiest and most maintainable way to do this. You could also encode that link with html in the description when you first create the description.

Comment: Is it possible to store the data like this? `New page available: [http://localhost:0000/app/NewItem](http://localhost:0000/app/NewItem)`? You could then use a markdown tool to render the data as HTML.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19221240/7720

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links